# How can I pass properties from parent to child and back to parent and to child?

Tags: vue.js

`openmyOverlay` triggers on button click in 'myComponent`.` isMyOverlayOpen`is set to false. Button click triggers`openmyOverlay`.` openmyOverlay`changes`isOverlayOpened`to true and passes to`myOverlay`.`   myOverlay`has`isOverlayOpened`prop and`overlayOpen`data.`isOverlayOpened`is being watched. Which changes`this.overlayOpen` to true. Clicking closes on overlay. But when I click on button again, overlay does not open.

```
<template>
    <button
      @click="openmyOverlay"
    >
      <myOverlay :isOverlayOpened="isMyOverlayOpen" />
    </button>
</template>

<script>
import myOverlay from "./myOverlay.vue";
export default {
  name: "my",
  props: {
  },
  components: {
    myOverlay,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isMyOverlayOpen: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    openmyOverlay() {
      this.isMyOverlayOpen = true;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

`myOverlay`

```
<template>
    <Modal
      v-if="overlayOpen"
      @triggerCloseOverylayInModal="closeModalOverlay"
      :overlayOpen="overlayOpen"
    />
</template>

<script>
import Modal from "......./modal";
export default {
  name: "myOverlay",
  components: {
    Modal,
  },
  props: {
    isOverlayOpened: Boolean,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      overlayOpen: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    openModalOverlay() {
      this.overlayOpen = true;
    },
    closeModalOverlay() {
      this.overlayOpen = false;
    },
  },
  watch: {
    isOverlayOpened() {
      this.openModalOverlay();
      this.isOverlayOpened = false;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use events to communicate from child to parent.

```
methods: {
  openModalOverlay() {
    this.overlayOpen = true;
    this.$emit('open');
  },
  closeModalOverlay() {
    this.overlayOpen = false;
    this.$emit('close');
  },
},
```

Then in your parent:

```
<myOverlay @close="isMyOverlayOpen=false" @open="openmyOverlay" overlayOpened="isMyOverlayOpen" />
```